# Data limits in server-sent events

Tags: javascript, html, server-sent-events, eventsource

I'm using server-sent events in order to execute queries on your database. The server streams the stats in realtime with `stats` events and when the query is executed, it sends `result` event with the data and closes the connection.

You can test it with this curl command:

```
curl 'http://rakam-production-webapp-203653584.us-east-1.aws.getrakam.com/query/execute?read_key=l2drg09t1j04poki16q46nsa7qvjdjhsedcml0e9m8sd87h6olkevq8b7m3m6948&data=%7B%22query%22%3A%22SELECT%20*%20FROM%20collection.%5C%22pull_request%5C%22%22%2C%22limit%22%3A1000%7D' -H 'Accept: text/event-stream'
```

The problem is that is the data is more than a few kilobytes, EventSource doesn't trigger `result` event.

http://jsbin.com/jiteca/edit?html,output

It works fine if the data is not that big:

http://jsbin.com/leginu/edit?html,output

I tried Chrome, Safari and Firefox and all of them suffer from this issue. Any idea about how to solve this problem? Is this the limitation of server-sent events, because I didn't find anything on [server-sent specification on W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-eventsource-20120426/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost certain your problem is server-side, not a problem with the browsers, or their implementation of SSE. When I test your curl command it ends abruptly at this point:

```
...null,null,null],["2016-08-30T14:08:03Z","MichMich",
```

(Slightly different on each run.)

Not just misformatted JSON, but no double LF. My guess is either your web server process has crashed, or your back-end script has crashed. Take a look in the logs? Or if not a crash, then some buffer has filled up. (The message looks to be just over 313,000 bytes, which isn't ringing any bells.)

You didn't tag anything for the server-side language or web server, so it is hard to guess beyond that.

Comment: I didn't even consider that my application may not be sending the full data. Thanks for pointing out!